# Jquery by default load the listbox dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
var myOptions_bench = {
1 : '1',
2 : '2',
3 : '3'}

$.each(myOptions_bench, function(val, text) {
    $('#test').append(
    $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
);
```

Here i want to load my own details.(Some times 1 to 3  some times 5 to 50). Dynamically i want to change the options. for loop is not working here.

Please do the needful. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more code? I guess `#text` is `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
var myOptions_bench = {
1 : '1',
2 : '2',
3 : '3'};

//remove current options
$('#test').html('');
//add new options
for(var i = 1;i < myOptions_bench.length+1 ;i++){
$('#test').append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `for` loop. You can set the start and end of the loop as per your need.

```
$('#test').empty();//Clear the list
for(var i = 1;i < 50;i++){
    $('#test').append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
 url: "mydetails.php",
 success: function(data){
 //process your data to var myOptions_bench
 }
});
```

[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) @jquery.com

Comment: Okay, got it ...  it is about the loop, not about the loading of dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax errors etc.

Try:

```
myOptions_bench = {
    1: '1',
    2: '2',
    3: '3'
}

$.each(myOptions_bench, function(val, text) {
    $('#test').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + text + '</option>');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MNk3a/